# How to get access token of my business facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My name is Alaa and i am the IT manager of my company,

We used our facebook app and the facebook PHP SDK to share our articles automatically from the backEnd of our website to our facebook pages. 
so we use the facebook graph API to retrieve the Access Token of our pages and use it in the php script.

But from February 13th, the script is not working anymore. I don't know what to do exactly, but looking on the internet, I found that we must use a new API (Marketing API) because we migrate our facebook account from default to business and we must have permissions (publish_pages, manage_pages), i want to inform you that we used the app several years without need to these permissions.

I want to add also that I can't show my business pages anymore in the list of all pages i manage (Personal and Business).

for example when i use facebook graph API to get access token of a page, i can just see my personal pages and not business pages of my company. i hope that you can anyone explain to me why?

I explain all of that on a video please click here to see it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhDerUakiNk

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can anyone help you please? I still can't find the solution :/

Comment: If you've used the Facebook SDK for several years, there's a chance that yours is deprecated. Facebook prefers 3.0, but a few older versions are still supported. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your server? That's what fixed it for me.